# Getting json in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending json data by ajax to controller but i can't my data in final.

## Code

`data that i send in playload`

```
[{specification_id: "6", text_dec: "1", product_id: "21"},…]
0: {specification_id: "6", text_dec: "1", product_id: "21"}
1: {specification_id: "7", text_dec: "3", product_id: "21"}
2: {specification_id: "31", longtext_dec: "fsg", product_id: "21"}
```

`controller`

```
public function addnewcustomsubspecifications(Request $reqss)
    {
        // dd($reqss->json()->all());

    //   $this->validate($reqss, array(
    //     'product_id' => 'required',
    //     'specification_id' => 'required',
    //     'text_dec' => 'nullable',
    //     'longtext_dec' => 'nullable',
    //   ));

      $datas = $reqss->json()->all();
      foreach($datas as $data){
          $add = CustomProductSpecification::create([
              'product_id' => $data['product_id'],
              'specification_id' => $data['specification_id'],
              'text_dec' => $data['text_dec'],
              'longtext_dec' => $data['longtext_dec'],
          ]);
          $parent = Specification::where('id', '=', $data['specification_id'])->first();
      }

      return response()->json(array('data'=>$add,'parent'=>$parent));
    }
```

If i comment my validation i will get:

```
"message": "Undefined index: longtext_dec",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
```

if not, i get:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"product_id":["The product id field is required."],"specification_id":["The specification id field is required."]}}
```

this is how my data are look like:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "specification_id" => "6"
    "text_dec" => "1"
    "product_id" => "21"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "specification_id" => "7"
    "text_dec" => "3"
    "product_id" => "21"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "specification_id" => "31"
    "longtext_dec" => "fsggf"
    "product_id" => "21"
  ]
```

> Note: I think the validation issue comes because of
>   `$this->validate($reqss, array(` I need to use something like
>   `$this->validate($reqss->json(), array(` but it's not possible this
>   way

## Ideas

1. I think my validation `$reqss` should be change to validate json code (as explained above)
2. if for any reason that's not possible to use validation, i think i need if statement for my `longtext_dec` and `text_dec` part in case when they are not provided, to be ignored and not return first error above.

> **PS: My thoughts could be silly for you but if i knew the true answer i
>   wouldn't ask here right? :)**

Well any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to evaluate each array individually. I can't think of anything off-hand that will validate multiple rows at once. However, since text_dec and longtext_dec can be nullable or missing, you'll need to take that into account when you get the values:

```
$add = CustomProductSpecification::create([
    'product_id' => $data['product_id'],
    'specification_id' => $data['specification_id'],
    'text_dec' => array_key_exists('text_dec', $data) ? $data['text_dec'] : null,
    'longtext_dec' => array_key_exists('longtext_dec', $data) ? $data['longtext_dec'] : null,
]);
```

The ternary will make sure the array has that column. If so, it will add the value, if not it will pass in a null value.